# MySQL how to select field or set null if field is null?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT (user OR NULL if field IS NULL)
FROM user
WHERE (
    field = 'id'
    OR field IS NULL
)
```

My database setup is

```
+-----------
| bookmarks 
+-----------
| id int not null primary key
| title varchar(255) not null
| url varchar(255) not null
| icon varchar(255)
| description varchar(255)
| addedby int foreignkey references users(id) on delete set null
+-----------

+-----------
| users
+-----------
| id int not null primary key
| email varchar(255) not null
| user varchar(255) not null
| pass varchar(255) not null
+-----------

+-----------
| user_bookmarks
+-----------
| user_id foreignkey references user(id) on delete cascade
| bookmark_id foreignkey references bookmarks(id)
| primarykey(user_id, bookmark_id)
+-----------
```

The query I am trying to modify is

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.*, MU.user, MUB.subscribers
FROM user_bookmarks UB, bookmarks B, users U, (
    SELECT bookmark_id, COUNT(bookmark_id) AS subscribers
    FROM user_bookmarks
    GROUP BY bookmark_ID
) AS MUB, (
    SELECT user, id
    FROM users
) AS MU
WHERE MUB.bookmark_id = UB.bookmark_id
AND B.id = MUB.bookmark_id
AND UB.user_id = $id
AND U.id = UB.user_id
AND MU.id = B.addedby
```

My query is probably horrible, SQL is not something I work with often.

What I want to do is to compensate for when a user is no longer on the system, (user who added a bookmark (`addedby`)) when the bookmark is looked up via an id of another use who is still subscribed (`U.id = $id`), I want to have the user field (`MU.user`) remain but be populated with `null`.

Example output (currently) using an `$id = 93`:

```
id, title, url, icon, description, addedby, user, subscribers
'93', 'title93', 'https://www.somewhere93.com', '', 'Something 93', '93', 'user93', '10'
'94', 'title94', 'https://www.somewhere94.com', '', 'Something 94', '94', 'user94', '10'
'95', 'title95', 'https://www.somewhere95.com', '', 'Something 95', '95', 'user95', '10'
'96', 'title96', 'https://www.somewhere96.com', '', 'Something 96', '96', 'user96', '10'
'97', 'title97', 'https://www.somewhere97.com', '', 'Something 97', '97', 'user97', '10'
'98', 'title98', 'https://www.somewhere98.com', '', 'Something 98', '98', 'user98', '10'
'99', 'title99', 'https://www.somewhere99.com', '', 'Something 99', '99', 'user99', '10'
'100', 'title100', 'https://www.somewhere100.com', '', 'Something 100', '100', 'user100', '10'
'102', 'title102', 'https://www.somewhere102.com', '', 'Something 102', '2', 'user2', '8'
```

id `101` is missing,  this is because (`SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE id = 101`) The field `addedby` is null, I want my query to also return the bookmark 101, similar to the other with only the `user` and `addedby` being null as the user no longer exists:

```
id, title, url, icon, description, addedby
'101', 'title101', 'https://www.somewhere101.com', '', 'Something 101', NULL
```

Comment: If field is `null` then your output will be absent; which is a `null`

Comment: If a field remains but is populated by null, by definition that field does *not* actually remain. Null is the **absence** of data.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT ID, IFNULL(User, 'N/A') User, COALESCE(User, Field, 'N/A') Field
FROM User WHERE (Field = ID) OR (Field IS NULL);
```

Comment: I updated my question, I am afraid I was being too simple, so I was unable to apply your solution (should it work).

Comment: "Something like this?" - That depends - can you add som explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want one row, which has the users value if available or a `null` value.  If so, one method is `union all`:

```
select u.user
from user u
where u.field = @id
union all
select null
from dual
where not exists (select 1 from user u where u.field = @id);
```

However, a simpler -- and probably more performant method -- is aggregation:

```
select max(u.user) as user
from user u
where u.field = @id;
```

Aggregation queries with no `group by` always return exactly one row.  If no rows match the `where` conditions then the value is `null` -- which is what you want.

Or, a similar approach with a subquery:

```
select (select u.user
        from user u
        where u.field = @id
        limit 1
      );
```

Comment: I am actually selecting multiple rows of bookmarks that the user is subscribed to. I updated my question with an example of what I get and what I am missing.